# Find limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow -2,y\rightarrow -2} \frac{e^{(x+2)^2-2x^2y+2xy^2} - e^{(y+2)^2-3x^3y+3xy^3}}{e^{x^3-x^2y} - e^{y^3-xy^2}} $

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim\limits_{{x\to -2\\y\to -2}} \frac{e^{(x+2)^2-2x^2y+2xy^2} - e^{(y+2)^2-3x^3y+3xy^3}}{e^{x^3-x^2y} - e^{y^3-xy^2}} $$

I use $e^a -1 \sim a $ and get:

$$\lim\limits_{{x\to -2\\y\to -2}} \frac{x^2+2x-2x^2y+2xy^2-y^2-2y+3x^3y-3xy^3}{x^3-x^2y-y^3+xy^2}$$

What to do next I have no idea. Convert all to the polar system does not give the desired result. Thanks a lot!